# Opencv TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv

Basically, I have this code that detects changes in background and boxed them. When I run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cam2.py", line 28, in <module>
    vertices = cv2.boundingRect(list(contours))
TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

c = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_,f = c.read()

avg1 = np.float32(f)

while(1):
    _,f = c.read()

    cv2.accumulateWeighted(f,avg1,0.1)

    res1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg1)

    absdiff = cv2.absdiff(f,res1)

    graydiff = cv2.cvtColor(absdiff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    retval, mask = cv2.threshold(graydiff, 50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, 18)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, 10) 

    contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) #not right

    while contours:
        vertices = cv2.boundingRect(list(contours))
        interest = vertices

        point1 = (interest[0], interest[1])

        point2 = (interest[0] + interest[2], interest[1] + interest[3])
        cv2.rectangle(f, point1, point2, cv2.RGB(255,0,0), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(mask, point1, point2, cv2.RGB(255,255,255), 1)

        contours = contours.h_next()

    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)

    cv2.imshow('img',f)
    cv2.imshow('avg1',res1)

    k = cv2.waitKey(20)

    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
c.release()
```

How do i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you trace your code!? What was the value for `contours` list?

Comment: the value is a very long array heres a snippet: 
       [[ 995, 1018]],

       [[ 995, 1019]],

       [[ 995, 1020]],

       [[ 995, 1021]],

Comment: It seems you have 4 contours that each of them contains just a point!?

Comment: So how would get multiple points instead?

Comment: Can you share your image?

Comment: it wont output anything due to the error

Comment: Hmm, Are you sure that your read frame is not empty?

Comment: Yes because I remember it working before I bothered adding the contours stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [findContour](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) doc it returns two things:

```
cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) → contours, hierarchy
```

Change the line to:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

That may works!

Comment: ah ofc. , missed that.

Answer (score 1):

contours is actually a double-array. the outer one is the list of  contours, the inner ones are the points of a single contour.

so, replace:

```
while contours:
    vertices = cv2.boundingRect(list(contours))
```

with:

```
for cnt in contours:
    vertices = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
```

and drop the

```
contours = contours.h_next()
```

line (you probably confused cv2 with the old c-api/cv approach, which was using linked lists under the hood)

Comment: Hmmm... Still not working (same error). But thank you for informing me with the last comment.

Comment: you probably got a different err now.

Comment: I wish :(
TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar