# Why, when I call cv2.boundingRect() on a single contour, does my code raise "TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar"?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am trying to write a fairly simple demonstration of some of the capabilities of a vision system for a robot. The program I am writing is supposed to find the largest contour in a thresholded image, then track the path of the center of the largest contour's bounding rectangle for the past 100 frames. However, when I call `cv2.boundingRect(bigCont)`, I see `TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`. I am using Python 2.7.9, Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit), and OpenCV 2.4.9.1, on Win7 SP1 64-bit. I have already looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092439/opencv-typeerror-points-is-not-a-numpy-array-neither-a-scalar/23092551#23092551) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628627/opencv-typeerror-contour-is-not-a-numpy-array-neither-a-scalar?rq=1); however, both of these seemed to involve setting `cv2.findContours` to a single variable, when the function in fact returns two values. My code already sets `cv2.findContours` equal to two separate variables, so I don't think that's the problem. The section of code involving isolating the center of the largest contour is:

```
    # find the largest contour in the thresholded image
    conts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    bigCont = []
    bigContSize = 0
    for cont in conts:
        contSize = cv2.contourArea(cont)
        if contSize > bigContSize:
            bigContSize = contSize
            bigCont = cont
    # find the center of the largest contour's bounding rectangle
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(bigCont)
    centerX = x + (w / 2)
    centerY = y + (h / 2)
    contCenter = (centerX, centerY)
```

And the full traceback of the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/newVisionDemo.py", line 73, in <module>
    showHist(orig)
  File "D:/newVisionDemo.py", line 51, in showHist
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(bigCont)
TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

As a secondary question, this was written based on a file we wrote earlier for the actual robot code. The API seems to indicate that `cv2.boundingRect` now returns only a single value, yet doesn't quite explain what that value represents. If someone could explain how to use the current implementation of `cv2.boundingRect`, that would be much appreciated.

Also, please feel free to let me know if you need to see more of the original code.

UPDATE: On a suggestion from another member of the team, I tried changing my call to `cv2.boundingRect` to `cv2.boundingRect(np.array(bigCont))`. This raised a different traceback, which I have included below:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (points.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (points.depth() == CV_32F || points.depth() == CV_32S)) in cv::boundingRect, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp, line 1895
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/newVisionDemo.py", line 68, in <module>
    showHist(orig)
  File "D:/newVisionDemo.py", line 48, in showHist
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(np.array(bigCont))
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1895: error: (-215) points.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (points.depth() == CV_32F || points.depth() == CV_32S) in function cv::boundingRect
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the threshold values, I determined that the error was being thrown because *there were no contours*--the binary image was completely black. I solved this by only attempting to find the center `if bigContSize > 0` and setting `contCenter` to `(0, 0)` otherwise (since it will be used later). That problem solved, I now turn to the next issue plaguing this code...